# Decoding response error in extjs

Tags: extjs3

I am doing the following stuff when a form is submitted. But I get this error:

Error decoding response: SyntaxError: syntax error

Here is my onSubmit success function:

```
onSubmit: function() {
    var vals = this.form.getValues();   
    Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ticketSession.php',
    jsonData: {
        "function": "sessionTicket",
        "parameters": {
            "ticket": vals['ticket']
        }
    },
    success: function( result, request ) {
        var obj = Ext.decode( result.responseText );
        if( obj.success ) {
            //alert ('got here');
            th.ticketWindow.hide();
            Web.Dashboard.loadDefault();

        }
    },
```

Here is my ticketSession.php

```
<?php
function sessionTicket($ticket) {
    if( $_REQUEST['ticket'] ) {
        session_start();
        $ticket = $_REQUEST['ticket'];
        $_SESSION['ticket'] = $ticket;
        echo("{'success':'true'}");

     }
    echo "{'failure':'true', 'Error':'No ticket Number found'}");

}
?>
```

I also modified my onsubmit function but didnt work:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ticketSession.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: { 
    ticket: vals['ticket']
    },
```

i am simply echoing this but I still get that error

```
echo("{'success':'true'}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you. It's a working example of an ajax-request which is nested in a handler.

```
var deleteFoldersUrl = '<?php echo $html->url('/trees/delete/') ?>';

function(){
            var n = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedNode();

            //FolderID
            var params = {'folder_id':n['id']};

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url:deleteFoldersUrl,
                params:params,
                success:function(response, request) {
                    if (response.responseText == '{success:false}'){
                        request.failure();
                    } else {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Success);
                    }
                },
                failure:function() {
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Error');
                }
            });
}
```